# Homotopic maps induce the same maps on homotopy groups given path connected spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Given pointed maps $f,g: (X, x_0) \longrightarrow (Y, y_0)$ that are pointed homotopic then $f_* = g_* : \pi_n(X, x_0) \longrightarrow \pi_n(Y, y_0)$.

Now let $X$ and $Y$ be path connected. Then if $f,g: X \longrightarrow Y$ are homotopic (not necessarily pointed homotopic) can we say $f_* = g_* : \pi_n(X,x_0) \longrightarrow \pi_n(Y, y_0)$?

Comment: You need a base-point to make sense of homotopy groups and the induced map. What is the meaning of $f_*$ when you omit the base-point?

Comment: As Hatcher writes "... if $X$ is path-connected ... one is justified in writing $\pi_n(X)$ for $\pi_n(X, x_0)$..."

Comment: This does not clarify anything since you are interested not just in a group up to an isomorphism (which is what Hatcher refers to).

Comment: Then can we say if $X$ and $Y$ are path connected then $f_* = g_* : \pi_n(X, x_0) \longrightarrow \pi_n(Y, y_0)$?

Comment: That would be a meaningful question as long as $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=y_0$. You then should edit the question accordingly. Try to find a counter-example with $n=1$, or at least include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Duplicate of this one? [Do freely homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism on fundamental groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852466/do-freely-homotopic-maps-induce-the-same-homomorphism-on-fundamental-groups)